# How to use Jenkins pipeline wrappers that do gracefully degrate?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

There are lots of Jenkins pipelines wrappers that do add extra functionality to pipeline and I am wondering if there is a way to write pipelines that do activate these wrappers when the plugins providing them are available but that will also work when the plugins are not available.

To explain this better I do have two examples of wrapper plugins that are very useful but even so, we should not break the pipelines if the plugins providing them are not available. There are too many cases when plugins can be temporary unavailable for some time (days, weeks) and we don't really want to break continuous integration because some optional functionality is broken.

- [timestamper](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper) - which adds timestamps to console output
- [ansicolor](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) - which enabled output of ANSI color escapes on console output

Current usage pattern, one that does *not* degrade gracefully:

```
timestamps {
    wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'XTerm', 'defaultFg': 1, 'defaultBg': 2]) {
    ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Related issue for ansiColor plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansicolor-plugin/issues/117